# Windows don't behave properly on a second monitor in GNOME3

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome

Using the unity interface i have no problems with my dual monitor setup. However, when i load gnome 3, windows placed on my second monitor don't act right.

I can only place windows on the left and right hand sides of the  second monitor, with a 'gap' in the center where no window can be placed. The second monitor seems to be divided into 3 sections, 1 (left), 2 (center), and 3(right) where windows can be placed in 1 and 3 but not 2. If i try to drag a window from 1 into 2, it 'jumps' to 3. Likewise if i try to drag a window from 3 to 2 it 'jumps' to 1.

I am running an optimus enabled laptop, nvidia geforce 540M. Drivers are not installed, and running bumblebee.

This does not happen on my laptop monitor, which I assume is the designated primary monitor.

The second monitor is connected via VGA.

This does not happen if i load with unity 3D.

I hope this is clear!!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experience exactly the same issue with gnome 3.2 on gentoo.
The problem goes away if you put the top panel into the external monitor (at the top of everything).
Probably, it would be a good idea to file a bug into the gnome bugzilla to geti it fixed for 3.4

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: How do you do that? Answered here http://askubuntu.com/questions/75903/how-do-i-put-the-top-panel-on-an-external-monitor-in-gnome3/76985#76985

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant response [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-shell-list/2012-November/msg00037.html)

in short, go:

> system-settings > display

and drag the toolbar to the monitor required.