# How do I put the top panel on an external monitor in GNOME3?

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, gnome

In Gnome 3, i would like to put the top panel on my external monitor in Ubuntu 11.10.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the `Displays` preferences app (Menu, type "disp", click on "Displays". Right-click on the rectangles representing your monitors, and you can drag them around to your heart's content.

Comment: Wow so subtle indeed haha